# Nodes appear out of line - views

Tags: views

Does anyone know what causes nodes to appear out of line when pulled to a view? Examples:

Photo profiles here:
https://international.permaculture.org.uk/about

Topics listed at the bottom of this page:
https://international.permaculture.org.uk/nextbigstep

I am wondering if it is because not all fields are populated - or because there are no teaser breaks and an uneven amount of body text?

Is there a way to stop this happening?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the photos page (that is, it is not obvious to me). It would be helpful you perhaps mocked up what you were expecting to see so that people can see a comparison of what you see and what you were expecting to see. Also, this is likely more of an HTML/theme question and less of a Drupal specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find the answer here:

[Responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

> With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues
>   where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as
>   one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a
>   .clearfix and our responsive utility classes.

If it is too difficult to add above mentioned classed divs in the layout (can be done via templating Views) you should add your own styling wherein you use the n-th group of CSS selectors to clear at the different media queries.

The problem arises from the fact that your views rows do not have equal height and therefore do not flow as you want it to.

Also look at this post [Bootstrap 3.0:responsive column resets section of the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172397/bootstrap-3-0responsive-column-resets-section-of-the-documentation)

And for a module to assist you can try this: [gido's sandbox: Views Bootstrap Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/gido/2456873)

> Views Bootstrap Responsive Grid module enable you to take advantage of
>   the Bootstrap 3 Grid System columns reset. With this module you can
>   define the number of items per row for each breakpoints. All of this
>   within the great configuration settings of the View module.